# Self stopping EC2 once task complete?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a lambda starting an EC2 hourly. The (windows) operating system on the EC2 runs a script on startup. The task can take anything from 1 minute to 45 minutes. I would like the EC2 to stop once the script has run.

I can think of one way to achieve this. I could install the aws cli on the EC2 itself and run something like `aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-07c1849fe7abcdef`. Doing so feels weird. Is there a better way?

#### Note

For complete clarity, I don't want to simply set a timer on the instance. Say I set a 45 minute timer, I would pay for 45 mniutes even when the task only takes 3 minutes. I would like the instance to stop immediately after the script has run, no matter how long the script took to run.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the AWS CLI to stop the instance on itself? I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: @CharlieFish is it bad practice to have the aws cli installed (with credentials) on the EC2 itself? My gut feel is that this would be bad practice?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of. The AWS Linux thing has the CLI installed by default. So some EC2 instances will already have it. And with IAM roles, it’s very common. I don’t see any problem with this.

Comment: @CharlieFish is right, you don't need credentials -- just an instance role that grants the permission... but you could also simply the instance power itself off with the `shutdown` command.  The EC2 infrastructure sees that happen and the instance transitions to the Stopped state, stopping billing.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That's really handy. I was half way through creating an IAM with (EC2 stop permissions only). I will try the shutdown method you recommend on the basis that it's simpler. Glad I know both methods though

Answer (score 1):

Your instance can use the operating system command to **Power Off**.

On Linux, it would be:

```
sudo shutdown now -h
```

(The `-h` means Halt, which will trigger the power-off. If not included, the operating system will stop but the instance will keep running.)

This can be used in conjunction with the [Instance Initiated Shutdown Behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingInstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior), which can either:

- **Stop** the instance (sounds like what you seek)
- **Terminate** the instance (good if a new instance is launched each time)

[image: Shutdown Behavior]
<sub>(source: [amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/images/shutdown_behavior_dialog.png))</sub>

No IAM permissions are required for this method.